# How to resolve "underscore" vulnerability found in nodemailer package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Any workaround for the **Underscore vulnerability found in nodemailer-smtp-transport**?
Tried installing the underscore package but did not resolve it.

Below is what I got after installing the package:
High            Arbitrary Code Execution in underscore

Package         underscore

Patched in      `>=1.12.1`

Dependency of   nodemailer-smtp-transport

Path            nodemailer-smtp-transport > smtp-connection > httpntlm >
underscore

Answer (score 0):

Tried following the steps in this link: https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d

Somehow resolved the vulnerability. Testing the package now. Hope it will send an email without any error.